# Bubble Sort ArrayIndexOutOfBounds in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<=4;j++)
                {
                    if(hand[j] > hand[j+1])
                    {
                        temp = hand[j];
                        hand[j] = hand[j+1];
                        hand[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I try to run this bubble sorting program, there's an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: `hand[5]` when `j == 4` and what is the size of array now ?

Comment: How big is your array?

Comment: @JigarJoshi Array is 5 elements big.

Comment: @ShreyashChaudhari Then hand[5] doesn't exist.

Comment: @Shahar Array is 5 elements big.

Comment: @Shahar How should I fix it?

Comment: @ShreyashChaudhari, Read the answer.

Comment: @ShreyashChaudhari I wrote an answer, it fixes it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing `hand[]` from index `0` to `5` (since it is `j+1`). Size of `hand[]` must be at least `6` for you to be able to do it. In your case, it is not, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens due the fact your array size is **5** thus the range is from **0-4** while you try to get in the last iteration the value from `hand[j+1]` that means **hand[5]** which produces this exception.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else said, when you have 5 elements in the array you can only access indices 0 to 4. As far as fixing goes, it should be:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<4-i;j++)
    {
        if(hand[j] > hand[j+1])
        {
            temp = hand[j];
            hand[j] = hand[j+1];
            hand[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i<4 in the outer loop will not work because I need i<5.

Comment: @ShreyashChaudhari I fixed the bubble sort for you. You don't need the last index.